# Missing CDT builder / how to tell eclipse that a project includes some C++

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse

I have a fully working pure java project and a fully working Java & C++ sample project in the same workspace. I decided to copy some of the C++ elements from the sample project and get them working in my previously java only project.

Eclipse seemed to know about how to handle the C++ parts in the sample project. Indeed I could delete the `.so` file in the `libs/armeabi-v7a` and then ask eclipse to rebuild the project and hey-presto a new `.so` file would appear and the program could then run again. Unfortunately the same could not be said of my original project. Eclipse seemed not to know what to do with the files in `/jni`, i.e. clicking on build project would not create an `.so` file (though I could create the so file from a DOS command line by typing `ndk-build`). Looking at the properties of the two projects I noticed that in the sample project, under "builders", it listed (amongst other things) a "CDT Builder" whereas in my original project it was not listed. I assume that this is the cause of the problem, but I can not work out how to get CDT Builder listed in my original project's properties.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** Highlight project name in eclipse, then right-click and select `android tools > Add native support`. Then add a dummie name for a library and click finish. This dummie name will appear with a cpp extension in the project's /jni directory. The CDT builder is now associated with the project. You can then delete the dummie file if you don't plan to use it.